# Maven cannot find richfaces 3.3.x in Central repo

Tags: maven, richfaces, command

I am trying to follow this tutorial:
http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/cdkguide/html_single/

I am hitting a roadblock with the maven commands. 
First the org.richfaces.cdk version 3.3.3.Final was not found in the central repository, so I had to manually install version 4.2.2.Final to my local repository by downloading the file *maven-richfaces-resources-plugin-4.2.2.Final.jar*
I then had to manually install the org.richfaces.cdk plugin to my local respository.
Next, to run the command in section 4.1. I had to change archetype:create to archetype:generate. Running this command showed that maven couldn't find META-INF/archetype.xml in the jar file. I am stuck at this point. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per this thread, that version of richfaces is in the JBoss Maven Repo, not Central
https://community.jboss.org/thread/172034?_sscc=t

In general, Software Vendors maintain their own Maven repos and do not push out every release to Central.  SpringSource, Atlassian, and Oracle (java.net) come to mind.

Archetypes are dependencies just like project dependencies / plugins, so you will likely need to add the JBoss repository to your pom.xml or settings.xml in order for the archetype to work. See the above link for how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! noahz's answer helped but wasn't the complete solution. I am still going to accept his answer. After substituting the Atlassion repo for the Jboss maven repo in settings.xml, I was still seeing the 'BUILD FAILURE' error saying it couldn't find the richfaces artifact. Maven was still looking in the central repo not in the Atlassian repo. So after a bit of research found that the central repo could be overriden with a  tag. Follow this link:http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html.

Build is now successful.

Comment: By the way, the central repo was overriden with the Atlassion repo.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Maven was still looking in the central repo not in the Atlassian repo."  Is your organization running a repository manager?

Comment: That was what the error message said, that maven cannot find the artifact in the central repo. I don't have the exact error message, but it was looking in the default central repo. Anyway, I am doing this on own machine, not at work.

Comment: Just to be sure - you know that you can declare multiple repos in your pom.xml and settings.xml, right?